# Combining the bisection method with Newton's method to find all real roots

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

I need to code an algorithm that finds all the real roots of a polynomial.
The given polynomial has only real roots . 
How do I combine bisection method with Newton's method to find ***all*** roots ?
Any tips or hints on how I should start is appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) will help you find all the roots, then you can drop the complex ones

Comment: What do you mean with "bisection"? Is it meant as the bracketing approach, that you shrink a bracketing interval with a guaranteed sign change inside? Or some kind of bisection-exclusion which finds increasingly more intervals guaranteed to not contain a root?

Comment: @caverac unfortunately it has to use both newton and bisection method.

Comment: @LutzL a regular bisection where you shrink an interval with a guaranteed sign change inside .

Comment: Do you have any idea how that should work? How do you find intervals with opposite signs? And then, perform a Newton step, accept if it lands inside the interval, shrink interval, if the shrink factor is less than, say, 2/3, tack on a bisection step?

Comment: @LutzL I also dont think it works with a regular bisection so what i did was use samuelson inequality to find the upper and lower bounds of real roots then find a random number within the interval use newton method to find one root and then use polynomial division to find the rest but that is without bisection .

Comment: The only thing you could then add on would be to take a deflated root, somehow use the last step size to construct a bracketing interval that has  a sign change with the original polynomial and "polish" the root using a bracketing method on the original polynomial. If the interval is small enough, bisection might be a sensible choice. But see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3021704/115115 about what numerical polynomial evaluation can look like under a microscope, there are limits on how much you can "polish" a root.